# Non-regular grid data

Tags: list-manipulation, data, grid-layouts

I have issue with non-regulary spaced data. I have set of 3 numbers `{x, y, z}` in my list.

```
data={{-33335.6,15525.1,20722.4},{-33231.7,15509.8,20723.5},<<99852>>,{-32909.4,26425.3,20957.6},{-33021.5,26438.1,20954.4}}
```

I can plot my data with `ListDensityPlot`.

I just want to get those data (interpolated) from the plot for further processing.
If one uses

```
ListInterpolation[data, { {Min[xValues], 
   Max[xValues]}, {Min[yValues], Max[yValues]}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

Interpolation is poor, I suppose because data are not on regular tensor grid. Is there way just to get what *Mathematica* is doing for `ListDensityPlot` ?

Comment: Could you post (at least) a sample of your data ?

Comment: for example

{{20959.8,24054.4,2022.6},{20959.1,24054.6,2044.44},{20959.8,24053.,2026.29},{20957.7,24054.6,2014.58},{20958.6,24054.,2034.33},<<39990>>,{16958.4,31988.8,2110.87},{16803.8,31820.2,2107.43},{16650.3,31654.6,2102.42},{16496.8,31486.9,2101.77},{16341.7,31320.,2098.09}}

Comment: Do not post data in a comment. Make the data available by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data you provided :

```
data = {{20959.8`, 24054.4`, 2022.6`}, {20959.1`, 24054.6`, 2044.44`}, {20959.8`, 24053.`, 2026.29`}, 
        {20957.7`, 24054.6`, 2014.58`}, {20958.6`, 24054.`, 2034.33`}, {16958.4`,31988.8`, 2110.8` }, 
        {16803.8`, 31820.2`, 2107.43`}, {16650.3`, 31654.6`, 2102.42`}, {16496.8`, 31486.9`, 2101.77`},
        {16341.7, 31320., 2098.09}};

ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: list density plot]

```
DensityPlot[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> All][x, y], {x, 16000, 21000}, {y, 24000, 32000}]
```

[image: density plot]

Comment: I forgot to say, I am using ver. 7                                                             DensityPlot[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> All][x, y], {x, 16000, 21000}, {y, 24000, 32000}]                                                                        it returns:   Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid. >>